# How to check invalid input case in the Asynchronous method?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to make `synchronous` and `asynchronous` behavior of my client program. So I created an interface (IClient) which has two methods, one is `getUserSync` which is for synchronous behavior and other is `getUserAsync` which is for asynchronous behavior.

Below is my Client program which implements my interface (IClient) -

```
public class RedClient implements IClient {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    @Override
    public RedResponse getUserSync(RedKey rdKeys) {

        // How to handle this case in getUserAsync method?
        if (RedUtils.isEmpty(rdKeys)) {
            return new RedResponse(null, RedClientError.INVALID_INPUT, RDClientStatus.ERROR);
        }

        RedResponse response = null;
        Future<RedResponse> handle = getHandle(rdKeys);

            try {
                response = handle.get(rdKeys.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                response = new RedResponse(null, RedClientError.TIMEOUT, RDClientStatus.ERROR);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                response = new RedResponse(null, RedClientError.ERROR, RDClientStatus.ERROR);
            }

            return response;
    }

    @Override
    public Future<RedResponse> getUserAsync(RedKey rdKeys) {

        // How to handle empty input keys case here just as I have handle it 
        // in getUserSync method

        return getHandle(rdKeys);
    }

    private Future<RedResponse> getHandle(RedKey beInput) {
        RedClientTask redClientTask = null;
        Future<RedResponse> future = null;

            try {
            RedClientTask = new RedClientTask(beInput);
            future = executor.submit(redClientTask);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

    return future;

    }
}
```

Now customer can call either `getUserSync` or `getUserAsync` method depending on there requirement. So in case of `getUserSync` method call, if they are passing Empty Input Keys, then I am making a response back that INVALID INPUT passed and returning it back..

Now how to do the same thing in `getUserAsync` method, as that method returns only Future so I am not sure how that is going to work out?

Comment: You have made the interface. Can't you modify that to be generic ? Okay, but you can also modify its `toString()` method in case of empty input - to return INVALID INPUT...

Comment: hmmm.. not sure how should I do this. Can you provide an example as I am newbie so not sure how to handle this scnenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in both cases; that's what it's for.

```
public Future<RedResponse> getUserAsync(RedKey rdKeys)  {
    if (RedUtils.isEmpty(rdKeys)) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("rdKeys can not be empty");
    }
    ...
}
```

That said ... I don't see what the issue is. You're returning a `Future<RedResponse>` ... that's a future that contains a `RedResponse`. In your `getUserSync` method you're using a `RedResponse` to indicate the invalid input.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is it a good practice to throw IllegalArgumentException for invalid inputs or we should make a error response and then send them back?

Comment: ::shrug:: personal preference. I prefer the exception as it's immediate when the method is called rather than something that has to be accounted for when processing a returned response (esp. when talking about async)